# How with python make photocopy effect like in photoshop

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Tried ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES from PIL, tried charcoal effect from imageMagick but get not what I want.
I want make this effect: [image: effect]
Please, help me found the way to make this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ImageMagick, something like this seems to be close. Convert to grayscale, then apply a Laplacian of Gaussian (or perhaps Difference of Gaussians) and then invert (negate) the colors so light becomes dark and dark becomes light. You can control the smoothness of the edging using by changing the x3 value. Larger will be broader and smaller will be finer edges.

[image: input]

```
convert flower_rose.jpg -colorspace gray -define convolve:scale=5! -morphology Convolve LoG:0x3 -negate result.png
```

[image: charcoal-like effect]